# Disabling "The client disconnected." errors in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis, error-handling

We have a global error handler in our ASP.NET application that logs and emails any exception errors that may happen.

One  error that is common to ASP.NET is the "The client disconnected." error that happens when they close a page while data is still being loaded.  The error itself is a non isue, however it gets logged and reported.

Is there anyway to disable this via an IIS or web.config file setting?

Or is basiclaly the only way around it to filter it with the global error handler code logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter it on the global error handler